# Customize Short keys - visual studio

Tags: visual-studio

hi i'm working in c# project. here i need to paste three texts alternatively more than 100 times, so its waste of time to copy all the three sentences in all the 100 times. so is there any customizable shortcut to save the sentence and it will be pasted when i press the shortcut key.

Answer (score 2):

Control-V will paste the last cut or copied item.

Control-Shift-V (VS Command `Edit.CycleClipboardRing`, control-shift-V is the deault keyboard binding) when pressed repeatedly will iterate through the buffer of all previously cut/copied items.

Ie. to get the last but one copied item press control-shift-V twice.